# Jenkins Build Pipeline to Publish Applications JAR for Multiple Paths

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a repository, where different project owners commit their use-case specific code into their designated sub-directory. You may think of such repo to look something like this:

```
repo_root
 |
 |-- proj_1 ------ 1_1_code --> 1_1_code.JAR
 |             |-- 2_1_code --> 2_1_code.JAR
 |             |-- 3_1_code --> 3_1_code.JAR
 |             ...
 |-- proj_2 ------ 1_2_code --> 1_2_code.JAR
 |             |-- 2_2_code --> 2_2_code.JAR
 |             |-- 3_2_code --> 3_2_code.JAR
 |             ...
 |-- proj_3 ------ 1_3_code --> 1_3_code.JAR
 |             |-- 2_3_code --> 2_3_code.JAR
 |             |-- 3_3_code --> 3_3_code.JAR
 |             ...
 |...
```

What I'd like to accomplish is to be able to build a Jenkins build pipeline, by which I'm able to:

- Build a new JAR for each and every subdirectory
- Publish the JAR file to a predefined path on Maven Artifactory or HDFS with different version (incremental).

Any idea who do go about this?

Comment: how do you build, with maven?

Comment: Where's your actual problem? Your question is very broad.