# Jenkins: archiveArtifacts - multiple distinct files

Tags: jenkins

The Jenkins docs say:

```
artifacts
You can use wildcards like 'module/dist/**/*.zip'. See the includes attribute of Ant fileset for the exact format. The base directory is the workspace. You can only archive files that are located in your workspace.

    Type: String
```

but I'm not clear how you add 2 separate artifacts.

Do you have 2 separate archiveArtifacts commands?
Or separate artifact filenames by a space?

E.g. 
`archiveArtifacts artifacts: "my.tar.gz my2.txt", fingerprint: true`

`archiveArtifacts artifacts: "my.tar.gz", fingerprint: true
    archiveArtifacts artifacts: "my.txt", fingerprint: true`

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts

Comment: Usually we put all our to be archived files into a folder and then directly archive the whole folder so you get all files by one command. 'archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'Test/*.*'

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32826133/2661253

Answer (score 4):

You can archive multiple files as artifacts.
you can use comma-separated file names as :

archiveArtifacts artifacts: "my.tar.gz, my2.txt"