# How to combine multiple files in a zipFile in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, zip

I wish to combine 3 files into a `zipFile` in my jenkins build. I have taken a look at these two sources ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823684/jenkins-multiple-artifacts-for-the-same-build/32826133#32826133), [2](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns)), but I cannot understand what that means for my example? My example is the following (generic example to hide real names):

```
zip zipFile: "myZip.zip", archive: true, dir: './someLocation1', glob: 'file1.py*'
zip zipFile: "myZip.zip", archive: true, dir: './someLocation2', glob: 'file2.py*'
zip zipFile: "myZip.zip", archive: true, dir: './someLocation3', glob: ''
```

The top two lines of code I want a specific file from each location, and the bottom line I want all files from that location, illustrated with the empty string ([reference](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/)) `glob: ''`. Of course this way is not correct and produces an error when it gets to the second line because `myZip.zip already exists`.

I want these files to be in the same zip because I want to then send the zip to storage. How can I  write this to achieve what I want? Is this the right way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. First copy all the files you need to a temp directory and then Zip that directory.

```
sh'''
mkdir tempDir
cp ./someLocation1/file1.py tempDir
cp ./someLocation2/file2.py tempDir
cp -r ./someLocation3/* tempDir/
'''

zip zipFile: "myZip.zip", archive: true, dir: './tempDir'
```

Comment: Yeah this would work totally fine, but I wanted to know if there was a way by just using one `zipFile` line. The second source I linked implies that it's possible

Comment: @pragmaticlearner You can't achieve your requirement with a single Glob pattern, so It's not possible to do with your approach.